# Sitecore agents on instances sharing a DB

Tags: sitecore

Our production Content Delivery environment has two web servers and one DB server that the two web servers share.

I know that there are a lot of DB related background tasks/agents that run in out-of-box Sitecore which do thing to the DB, like clean up tables, etc. Is it ok to have both web servers doing these tasks? Or are there tasks that should be turn off on the second server so that both aren't trying to do the same thing on the same DB? I don't see anything about this specifically in their Scaling Guide. Thanks.

Comment: Is one of the web servers used for content management or is that separate? The scaling guide talks about removing configuration for servers that are used for content delivery only.

Comment: Updated the first sentence to be clear. I'm just talking about the CD environment. We have a separate CM environment that has one web server and one DB server. What do you mean by "removing configuration"? We've followed the scaling guide, but there doesn't seem to be anything in there that's specific about the scenario I described

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware that are not any issues with this setup - I have sites running like this with no issues. As long as both CD web servers only share Web and Core databases you should be fine.

Section 3.1 (Configuring a Publishing Target) in the Scaling guide has this setup on a diagram where the Core and Pub databases are shared between the two CD boxes. 
The Pub database is just another Web database that is configured with a publishing target.